# Writing to a website with a Java application (JWS)

Tags: java, file-io, webserver, java-web-start

I'm writing an application that requires some front end user interaction that I'm hosting on a website, to be executed via Java Web Start.

Basically when the program is executed, there will be some input prompted and then a it runs some calculations, the results of which are displayed on the GUI. What I'd like is to somehow have my application saved the data in a text file on the webserver, or better yet, talk to the server itself and write to a file already on the server.

Is this possible? I'm just using a free webhost, so I don't have a huge suite of tools at my command for exercising a lot of control over the server itself. I wonder if since the application is hosted on the file system (on the webserver), could I not just write a file like any old other file system, or are there privilege problems there?

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* Yes. *"..I'm just using a free webhost,.."*  That adds a 'level of difficulty' to the problem.  To accept uploads the server must be dynamic (e.g. ASP, JSP, PHP as opposed to HTML).  'Free sites' typically do not offer the former.

Comment: @AndrewThompson But assuming a free host did, what would the process be like? What if, perhaps, the application in question (to be run on the webite) was a sever. Would it be possible using the Java Socket API to connect to and talk to this application (via some sort of GUI client)? Would it be easier to write files to the user's space instead of on the webserver?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Depends what you think is 'easier'.  A JWS app. that writes to the local file-system would either need to use the JNLP API services or be fully trusted.